# button OnClick event not firing

Tags: javascript

There is a page and I am trying to attach an onclick event to the button ("SEARCH CRUISES") on the page but the onclick event is not firing correctly. Here is my code:

```
<script>
debugger;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cdc-filters-search-cta")

for (i=0; i< x.length; i++){
    if(x[i].text.trim().indexOf("SEARCH") >= 0 &&  x[i].text.trim().indexOf("CRUISES") >= 0){
        x[i].onclick = function(){
            console.log("Search button clicked");           
        };
        break;
    }   
}
```

Here is the complete html: https://jsfiddle.net/g0tkqrx6/

I have tried attaching the onclick event to the object in many different ways but I am not able to get the click event to fire. I would appreciate if anybody can provide some insight as to what I could be doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your onclick will register only if it's met the 'if' condition. What is the values that you providing for text?

Comment: can you attach your html as well?

Comment: when i debug, I am able get inside the if condition and access the object (button) but when i click on the object, the click event is not firing

Comment: how many objects(button) you have? why are you using 'break' in loop?

Comment: there should be 1 object with the name "Search Cruises"...hence I don't need to search any further and I wish to break out of the loop

Comment: Your javascript function have no errors it is firing onclick eevnt. Add alert('ok'); in side function and test.

Answer (score 0):

You must use textContent for element text and make it uppercase.

Here is an example:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cdc-filters-search-cta")

for (var i=0; i< x.length; i++){
    var  element = x[i]  ;
    if((element.textContent ).toUpperCase().indexOf("SEARCH") >= 0 &&  element.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf("CARS") >= 0){
        element.onclick = function(){
            console.log("Search button clicked");           
        };
        break;
    }   
}
```

```html
<button class="cdc-filters-search-cta"> SEARCH</button>
<button class="cdc-filters-search-cta"> CARS</button>
<button class="cdc-filters-search-cta">SEARCH CARS</button>
```

Comment: 'If' loop is not a problem here as per Op he is able to access the element in loop.

Comment: search cars fired as well in my example

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your html would be helpful. Make sure you are interacting with the correct names for your js events.

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle link in my description

Answer (score 0):

Well to start with I think you should really take a look at this article on why you shouldn't add inline functions or css.
https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/coding-styleconventions/why-inline-comments-are-generally-a-bad-idea/

Secondly I think your issue is that you are trying to add a click event to an angular front end which is controlled by the ngModel and also the site is probably compiled AOT. However you can try this,

```js
    let x = document.querySelectorAll('.cdc-filters-search-cta');

    let term = /[(SEARCH)(CRUISES)]/

    x = Array.from(x);

    x.forEach(span => {
        if (term.test(span.textContent)) {
            return span.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                console.log('span clicked')
            });
        }

    })
```

I changed your code to querySelectorAll which returns an array and I used a forEach loop to add an eventListener. Not sure how well that will go down with your angular, but maybe.